# Two different definitions of database schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

a) I found two definitions of schema:

> FIRST - A set of information that describes a table is known as a schema,
>   and schemas are used to describe specific tables within a database, as well
>   as entire databases (and the relationship between tables in them, if any).
>
> SECOND - A database schema is a way to logically group objects such as tables, views, stored procedures etc. Think of a schema as a container of objects.

I assume the two descriptions describe entirely different concepts, which just happen to use the same name?

b)

> A database schema is a way to logically group objects such as tables, views, stored procedures etc. Think of a schema as a container of objects.

If I understand the above definition correctly, then database schema is similar to a namespace, only difference being that we can assign access permissions to database schema, while same can’t be done with namespaces?

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be confusing.  Generally, in the context of relational databases in general, your **schema** is the collection of your database structures - your tables, views, keys, constraints, etc.  Depending on whom you ask, this may or may not include triggers, user-defined functions, custom user types, stored procedures, and the like, but I lump them in as schema objects, as well.

Within the context of specific relational database management systems (e.g., MSSQL, Postgres), a *schema* is a logical grouping of database objects.  It serves two purposes: 1) as you note, it acts as a namespace and allows you to group related database objects together, and reduces name collision; 2) you can assign security settings to the *schema* as a whole, rather than assigning permissions to the *schema*'s objects individually.

The terminology collision is sometimes confusing, but intentional.  It usually makes sense to talk about subsets of your entire **schema**, and to assign permissions and deal with behaviors on these subsets - and the database supports this by allowing you to group these subsets into their own *schemas*.